# Send webpage as image or pdf

Tags: php, image, pdf

I have a form that contains a grid wherein the customer can click on different cells to visually create a configuration. When they are done, there must be an email with a PDF or image attached to it.

Is it possible to create an image or a PDF of a div or a form and send it directly by mail, without it is necessary to save it to the clients PC first?

Comment: When you say webform are you talking about asp.net ?

Comment: HTML, PHP and jQuery if possible. I have no knowledge of ASP.net

Comment: I have thought something else myself. I create a grid with div's or a table, with a onclick feature and a hidden input box. At the submit, I create an email that includes a table with the desired configuration.